# check 2 lists against each other

Tags: c#

say i have two lists of fruit. my first list has an apple, orange, and banana. my second list has orange, banana, and apple. i'm not sure if the order of these items in the list will matter. i want to compare the lists and if they are equal to each other, then i do something. will this compare all the objects in the list no matter what the order?

```
   foreach(Fruit fruit1 in list1)
      foreach(Fruit fruit2 in list2)
      {
          if(fruit1.Equals(fruit2)
          //do something
      }
```

Comment: no. foreach will iterate through each list in order. you'd need to use `.Contains()` to check if one item is included in the other list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest implementing an `IEqualityComparer` for your Fruit class. Something like this (assuming that you are comparing on a `Name` property):

```
public class FruitEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Fruit>
{
    public bool Equals(Fruit f1, Fruit f2)
    {
        if (f1.Name == f2.Name)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Fruit fruit)
    {
        return fruit.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can check for equality like this:

```
var areEqual = fruit1.SequenceEqual(fruit2, new FruitEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: +1. I always forget about `SequenceEqual`. Removed my answer.